# CSS Grid with variable height to make it work like masonry layout

Tags: html, flexbox, css-grid, grid-layout, masonry

I'm trying to create masonry layout using css grid layout. All items in grid have variable heights. The items in the next row should stack to available space of the items in the previous row. i tried using `flex-flow: row wrap` but it doesn't work. Below is what i'm trying to achive.

[image]

Html Markup:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="g grid-33">Item 1</div>
  <div class="g grid-66">Item 2</div>
  <div class="g grid-33">Item 3</div>
  <div class="g grid-33">Item 4</div>
  <div class="g grid-33">Item 5</div>
  <div class="g grid-66">Item 6</div>
  <div class="g grid-33">Item 7</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 15px 15px 0 0;
  background: #CDD6D0;
}

.g {
    background: #E16036;
    border: 4px solid #E3170A;
    border-radius: 8px;
    padding: 15px;
    color: white;
    font: 18px Arial;
    margin: 0 0 15px 15px;
    height: fit-content;
}

.grid-25 {
  width: calc(25% - 15px);
}

.grid-33 {
  width: calc(33.3333% - 15px);
}

.grid-50 {
  width: calc(50% - 15px);
}

.grid-66 {
  width: calc(66.6666% - 15px);
}

.grid-100 {
  width: calc(100% - 15px);
}

.g:nth-child(2) {
    height: 100px;
}

.g:nth-child(3) {
    height: 90px;
}

.g:nth-child(6) {
    height: 100px;
}

.g:nth-child(5) {
    height: 90px;
}
```

[Codepen link](https://codepen.io/shameerrulz/pen/abPwQbx?editors=1100)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS-only masonry layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44377343/css-only-masonry-layout)

Comment: No, the answer suggests using columns, i want to use rows

Comment: works in both way and the answer remains the same. There is no full support for grid-masonry yet only with experimental features enabled on FF.

Comment: That means there is no way to achieve the desired layout without using position absolute and only using css flex/grid which works on major browsers?

Comment: position absolute will not help you here either as you need to calculate the width and height of the other elements to prevent collisions.

Comment: width will be always fixed, only height varies

Comment: but your width will not be the same for all elements. It will span into other columns and as such the content height of the column needs to be calculated so that an element such as item 6 will not collide with previose elements

Comment: @sam This isn't possible in CSS only; you need to rely on JavaScript until the masonry-axis feature is implemented in all browsers. You may want to remove the [tag:grid-layout] tag (since it is redundant with [tag:css-grid] and [tag:masonry] anyway), and add the [tag:javascript] tag, if a JS solution is acceptable to you. Given the bounty, I'm sure you'll receive plenty of answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `rows` and `columns` should be compatible with `grid-template`.
check out this solution

```css
.container {  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 1fr);
  gap: 1em 1em;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  padding: 1rem;
  grid-template-areas:
    "a b b"
    "c b b"
    "c d e"
    "f f e"
    "f f g";
}

.a { grid-area: a; }

.b { grid-area: b; }

.c { grid-area: c; }

.d { grid-area: d; }

.e { grid-area: e; }

.f { grid-area: f; }

.g { grid-area: g; }



html, body , .container {
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background: #fff;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue";
  color: #A770F1;
}

.container > div[class] {
  background: #ececec;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.black {
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="a black">a</div>
  <div class="b">b</div>
  <div class="c">c</div>
  <div class="d">
d
  </div>
  <div class="e">
 e
  </div>
  <div class="f">
f
  </div>
  <div class="g">g</div>

</div>
```

Comment: This solution works perfectly when adding "height: fit-content" for all child div within container class!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create your image with the grid system with the code below using the grid system as was hinted by you with a grid 3fr wide and 8fr long.

**widths**

To create the width items with class grid-33 have span 1 fraction and items with class grid-66 span 2 fractions in width

**heights**

in your picture item 1, 4 and 7 are around 2 / 3ths of the the other items. Because of this there height is set to 2 fractions and the remaining are set to 3 fractions.

**gaps**

To keep the correct gaps I kept your margins as grid-gap didnt seem to work.
and to give the items the correct height I changed heigth to auto, so there are no empty spaces.

```css
/*CSS */
.container {
  display: grid; /* changed */
  padding: 15px 15px 0 0;
  background: #CDD6D0;
  
  grid-template: repeat(8, 1fr) / repeat(3, 1fr); /* added */
}

.g {
    background: #E16036;
    border: 4px solid #E3170A;
    border-radius: 8px;
    padding: 15px;
    color: white;
    font: 18px Arial;

    grid-row-end: span 2; /* added */
    grid-column-end: span 1; /* added */
    
    margin: 7.5px; /* changed */
    height: auto; /* changed */
}

.g-h-3 {
  grid-row-end: span 3; /* added */
}

.grid-33 {
  grid-column-end: span 1; /* added */
}

.grid-66 {
  grid-column-end: span 2; /* added */
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML Markup: -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="g grid-33">Item 1</div>
  <div class="g grid-66 g-h-3">Item 2</div>
  <div class="g grid-33 g-h-3">Item 3</div>
  <div class="g grid-33">Item 4</div>
  <div class="g grid-33 g-h-3">Item 5</div>
  <div class="g grid-66 g-h-3">Item 6</div>
  <div class="g grid-33">Item 7</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. OP wants a masonry grid. Which means that **any** item in the grid could have a different height. Test your code by making Item 4 twice as tall. The vertical gaps don't close between the left column elements.

Comment: @disinfor The provided solution can be used to create the image the OP wanted. But it's not responsive to changes outside of that. You could extend the code to make other kinds of grids possible but you will only make it responsive to changes in height and position with JavaScript.

Comment: The OP doesn't want just that image. Look at the question. _All items in grid have variable heights._ Your solution builds that image but not what they want

Comment: @Armaniimus your code doesn't work well with the variable height, for ex: set the height: max-content, it doesn't stack and vertical gaps visible, is there any way to make the height variable and make it work like a masonry layout?

Comment: @Sam See the accepted answer. Further more thanks for asking the question I learned alot from puzzeling on it.

Answer (score -1):

There is an upcoming specification that adds masonry layout to the grid module of CSS. Unfortunately it is not supported by any browser yet: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_grid_layout/Masonry_layout

In my VueJS apps I'm using the following plugin for masonry layout: https://vue-masonry-wall.yeger.eu/ It works well enough.

Maybe you can dig into the code and figure out how they have implemented it.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter but whoever is probably downvoted this because it's really more of a comment than an answer; you're informing OP about something that isn't usable yet and not even telling them how to use it once it is.

Comment: See, the thing is: SO wants to be the one true source of dev knowledge, so this thread might become the go-to place for this question for all eternity. How often have you looked something up and Google led you to a thread that is several years old but gives you the right answer? So maybe my answer is not useful now, but it will be useful in a year or two or even 10.

Comment: If your answer will be useful in 10 years then you can post it in 10 years.

Comment: Yeah, sure. As if I rememeber this question and then come back and say: now the draft is implemented, I waited 10 years to post this information that I could have posted 10 years ago.

Comment: I down voted for the specific reasons @TylerH mentioned. This is a comment. And you're asking the OP to dig into Vue.js code to see how it works instead of posting a solution. Also, once masonry layout gets implemented, this: _There is an upcoming specification that adds masonry layout to the grid module of CSS._ becomes irrelevant.